# How does C compiler handle post-increment (i++), memory wise?

Tags: c, gcc, increment, c99

I've been just explaining `i++` vs `++i` details to a friend. I was telling him how with **no optimalization**, `i++` in `for` loop essentially means making a copy of your `i` that is not used for anything. Since `i++` can be described with this pseudocode:

```
tmp = i;
i = i + 1;
return tmp;
```

Well, I noticed I just don't really know one thing: where is the memory for our `tmp` allocated? Does it increase the memory size required for whole procedure/function? (That is, is it on stack?)

I suppose it is, but how to test that? **If and only if it matters** we're talking about C99 standard and GCC compiler. But I'd prefer broader answer to get some perspective on the matter.

Comment: Your compiler wouldn't produce different assembly for those at all. (We're considering i is a builtin type.)

Comment: @DeiDei I guess I should've bolded the **no optimization** part. Also, I never said I'm only asking for this when the value is not used. Not mentioning that I also didn't assert I only care about built-in types.

Comment: Depends on where `tmp` was allocated. Incrementing doesn't affect that at all. Is `tmp` a reference?

Comment: For built in types I believe the store is just reordered so it stores and then increments instead of increment and then store.

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote? I don't see what did I miss where writing this question...

Comment: @TomášZato It was mine. Your example is incomplete, and your question is unclear.

Comment: There is no well defined difference between "optimization" and "no optimization". The C standard does not specify the machine code to be generated for a given C construct. It only specifies the behavior of that construct. If a compiler is able to implement the semantics of `i++` without creating a temporary, it's free to do so. If it does create a temporary, that temporary is not part of the semantics of the C construct.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm sorry but if we only consider C language, even specific standard and specific compiler, I don't know what am I expected to clarify. I just wanted to know how it interally works and understand it a little. Sorry for distrupting the stream of gimme teh codes questions...

Comment: @TomášZato Start with a [MCVE] as usually required here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would you expect me to post five questions, each with slightly different (but exactly defined) use of `i++` operation?

Comment: @TomášZato I'm expecting you to post _one clear question_, that's all.

Comment: Not every question tagged "C" has to be about quoting the C standard (or pointing out that no part covers this situation). For example, this question is also tagged "gcc" so it's possible to examine what some particular version of gcc does in this regard.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm sorry, but I'm afraid that I do not know what to edit to make the question clear enough. But all answers exactly reflect what I wanted to know. Maybe some of answerers would know how should I write my question more clearly?

Comment: @TomášZato Have a look at your question title. Why do you think there's any extra memory needs to be allocated for incrementing a value? That's most probably done with a single op on a register. At least implementation defined, as the accepted answer shows.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Now you're criticising that I didn't know that "*it's most probably done with a single op on a register*" as you say. You're criticising that there's some misconception in my question, but come on. If I didn't have misconceptions and holes in my knowledge, I wouldn't be asking questions now, would I?

Comment: @TomášZato - perhaps the complaint is that your question makes an assumption (that extra memory is allocated), and then makes a further question based on that assumption. If the original assumption turns out to be (sometimes) false, as it does here, it makes the question harder to answer. Still I found it clear enough! If you wanted to make it clearer you could phrase it like "How does the compiler implementation of pre vs post-increment of a primitive vary?" or "Is it always more efficient to pre-increment _primitive_ values"?

Comment: You could also clarify if `i` is a primitive (I assumed it was) or a more complex type. The answer is very different across the two cases!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption that compilers always produce different results for `++i` and `i++` **without optmization** is false. Here's a look at pre and post increment [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/yKDrk1), in gcc 6.2, no optimization:

#### The C Code

```
int pre() {
  int i = 0;
  ++i;
}

int post() {
  int i= 0;
  i++;
}
```

#### The Assembly (x86-64)

```
pre():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret

post():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Note that the compiled code is byte-for-byte identical here for `i++` and `++i`. Both simply add 1 to the memory location reserved on the stack for `i`. No temporary is created or needed.

You might complain that I'm not actually using the value of the incremented expression, so let's [look at something](https://godbolt.org/g/YL0dpQ) that actually does use the value:

#### The C Code

```
int pre(int i) {
  return ++i;
}

int post(int i) {
  return i++;
}
```

#### The Assembly (x86-64)

```
pre(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        pop     rbp
        ret

post(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        lea     edx, [rax+1]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Here, the assembly is different. The pre-increment version uses a memory RMW (read-modify-write) instruction to increment the variable, while the post-increment version increments the variable separately through `edx`. While looking at un-optimized code is always an exercise in futility, I'm quite sure the post-increment version is *faster* here, as the dependency chain is smaller due to no RMW instruction in the critical path and subsequent store forwarding stall.

A key note is that even here there is no "temporary space" allocated in memory - only the assembly changes, and a register (`eax` here) is used for free as the resting place for the value of `i` before the post-increment.

Of course, you shouldn't really read *anything* into unoptimized code. It isn't going to be used in practice and you can't really learn much about the efficiency of any construct by studying it, because the optimized code will vary wildly across different idioms.

So finally, let's look at [a realistic example](https://godbolt.org/g/K9i7QX) where we are using optimization, and *both* the value of the increment expression and the underlying variable is actually used (so neither value is optimized away). Here we take an `int &` reference to i in each function so that the passed-in value is modified. We use -O2, although every other optimization level I tried produces identical results, other than `-Os`:

#### The C Code

```
int pre(int& i) {
  return ++i;
}

int post(int& i) {
  return i++;
}
```

#### The Assembly (x86-64)

```
pre(int&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     eax, 1
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
        ret

post(int&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        lea     edx, [rax+1]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], edx
        ret
```

Both functions are almost exactly the same cost. They have the same number of instructions, and on modern Intel hardware produce the same number of uops (4 fused-domain) with the same cost. The functions take exactly the same number of instruction bytes<sup>1</sup>.

The post-increment differs in that it uses a `lea` instruction to put its result in `edx`, so that `eax` remains un-incremented as the return value. The pre-increment version simply uses `eax` for everything. The use of `edx` has no direct cost here because it is a scratch register in x86-64, so there is no need to save its value. In a more complex code, the use of another register *could* increase register pressure, although it is fairly unlikely because the lifetime is very small and there are more opportunities for re-ordering.

The post-increment version actually has a smaller dependency chain for the return value - assuming the caller uses the return value in `eax`, it will take 1 additional cycle for it to be ready (since the `add eax, 1` is part of the dependency chain). That's actually inherent in the pre-increment definition: *in one way, pre-increment is slower*, because the increment and subsequent use of the value must occur serially, while in the post-increment case they can occur in parallel, since the use of the value doesn't depend on the increment operation. Of course, this effect is very small - not usually more than a single cycle. The classic advice to use pre-increment probably still applies because for objects it can make a *big* difference. For primitives, not so much.

---

<sup>1</sup>Interestingly, the pre-increment version could have been implemented with `inc eax` rather than `add eax, 1`, which is probably as fast on modern hardware and saves a byte. It probably isn't because of the mostly obsolete advice to avoid `inc` and `dec` due to partial flag stalls. In fact, with `-Os` (optimize for size) gcc *does* use an `inc` here.

Comment: By not storing the return value of the increment this is a little misleading.

Comment: Sure, but so is looking at the code without optimization. My point was to show that the compiler doesn't just uniformly translate the post-increment version into the version using a `tmp` variable on the stack. Even with optimizations off, it is smart enough to avoid it. I added a version where the value of the incremented expression is consumed, and commented on it as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write all this, it's highly appreciated!

Comment: What is RMW in "a memory RMW instruction"?

Comment: It is read-modify-write. An instruction like `add [rsp], 1` is an RMW instruction because it has both a memory source and destination. The CPU needs to read the value from memory, perform the "add 1" part in the ALU, then write the result back to memory. If any of the values (the initial value or the final value) are ever needed in nearby code, it's best to avoid an RMW instruction, since you'll end up reading the result back which causes a store-forwarding stall and is slower regardless. So you don't see a ton of RMW instructions generated by compilers, except for simple isolated code.

Comment: @TomášZato - no problem. I updated it with a look at what happens when you use optimization.

Comment: I disagree with "there is no "temporary space" allocated in memory - only the assembly changes, and a register (eax here) is used for free...", using a register is in fact a kind of memory allocation; may be the word allocation seems too strong, but at least the register is where the value is stored and that answers the question.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - we'll I'm using the definition of "memory" that I think is commonly understood - the virtually addressable space generally stored in RAM, returned by `malloc` and so on. The distinction between registers and memory is very clear when you look at the hardware, although less clear when you look at C code, where the compiler may do magic. I was very clear that it uses an extra register and that may be slower in some cases (but not here).

Comment: Finally note that in plenty of cases there is no temporary at all! I constructed my example so that a temporary was in fact needed, but in a most complex function it's highly likely that the compiler just re-orders things and uses no temporary _space_ at all, not even registers. For example, `foo(i++)` may compile to effectively `call foo; inc i` and `foo(++i)` to `inc i; call foo`.

Answer (score 5):

For primitive types, prefix vs. postfix only affects the ordering of the increment step. Compare `printf("%u", i++);` to `printf("%u", ++i);`. The pseudo assembly for the former might be something like (assumes `i` is in a register already):

```
load "%u" to arg1register
move i to arg2register
call printf
increment i  // Could occur before call to printf if arg2register separate from i
```

while for the latter, it just reorders the increment step:

```
load "%u" to arg1register
increment i // Could occur at any point before this and after last use of i
move i to arg2register
call printf
```

In a `for` loop increment step, *even with optimization off*, `i++` and `++i` would be the same, *because the "result" is unused*; it doesn't need to be loaded, moved, etc., so it's just `increment i`.

If it's not a primitive type, then it's calling the appropriate `++` overload, and it's up to the postfix `++` overload to make a copy (which would usually be stored on the stack, like any other variable) before incrementing in place and returning the copy. Even in a `for` loop increment step, it can't guarantee that postfix operation is equivalent to prefix, so barring extreme compiler optimizations (that may not be standard legal), `i++` for non-primitive types would have to call the postfix operator, creating and destroying a temporary unnecessarily.

This is inefficient, which is why it's considered good practice to stick with prefix increment in C++ all the time; if your code changes from using `int` to, say, `mpz_class`, you don't want to end up making and destroying an `mpz_class` on every increment. Since prefix is harmless for primitives, and *much* better for user-defined types, just use prefix unless it would be much uglier to do so (and even then, only if it's a primitive).

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, it is an automatic variable, and it's place in memory is left to compiler.
Practically, it depends on whether you are talking about built-in operator or user-defined operator, return type and your ABI.
For example, for built-in increment done on integer type, on X64 CPU, the return value of an integer is put in the register. So the variable does not occupy any space and at all.

Comment: I don't see what `tmp` actually is from the question!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I guess, this is the actual question - what this `tmp` is? I understand the question as an attempt of OP to understand what compiler is doing semantically.

Answer (score 2):

No extra memory is required.  With ++i or i++ the value of i exists in memory, it is loaded into the processor, place into a register, a cpu instruction increments it (either addition or an increment instruction depending on the processor), the result ends up in a register, and then the result is saved to the same location in memory where i came from.

The difference between ++i and i++ is really just sequence of processor instructions.  i++ will imply ensure that whatever else that the value of i is used for happens first, using the initial value, before the value is incremented.

If the value is not being used elsewhere, there will be literally no difference in the resulting machine code.